# Python gets wierd on me when I make it executable

Tags: python, software-design, cx-freeze, xlsxwriter

I have written a program for my friend's insurance company because he asked me to and I want to prove to my friend that I can (noobly) program to some extent.

I wrote a program that works in my IDE (Pycharm) on python3.4. It has a GUI and it worked. Then I made it an executable (i did this using cx_Freeze, creating the proper setup.py file and then using command prompt on the folder and C:\pythonpath\python.exe setup.py bdist_install

The executable worked and I was so happy! My program takes information from the web and outputs it to an excel file. 
After I while, I found out something was wrong, and so I went back through the code and fixed the error. Running it in my IDE = it worked and perfectly fine.

When I tried to make it into an executable again, this time the program didn't finish when I ran it through the GUI (It usually takes information then outputs it then its done)! I've tried remaking the installer multiple times, but I'm not too sure what to do now. Does anybody know or have any idea on how to proceed? It was working like a few weeks ago...

I know its a longshot, but if anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated! 
It goes like this : 
There's a folder with a file called insurance_premiums.py ([pastebin code here](http://pastebin.com/NbryTPvA))

Then a setup.py file ([code here](http://pastebin.com/j45iJe7k))

and theres also 2 pictures, 1 .gif and 1.ico

Does anybody know what's wrong? Do I have to delete all previous setup.py files? Because I tried rerunning the thing to make it into an executable multiple times and so when I click on my setup.py file for some reason in my IDE the top left corner says C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\setup.py1.tmp   iono why

Comment: "I have written a program for my friend's insurance company because he asked me to and I want to prove to my friend that I can (noobly) program to some extent. " - that's possibly the *worst* decision your friend has ever made. As to "Does anybody know what's wrong?", see my previous sentence on the wisdom of hiring people just because they're friends :-)

Comment: im not getting paid, i did this out of free will.

Comment: my program isnt ending. It's going through all the code right up until it is supposed to "end" and close the workbook. No workbook is created.

Comment: Kenny, I suspect you mean "good will" rather than "free will". The former is good intent, the latter an illusion of the way our brains work :-)

Comment: its only like this when i run it through the installer -> open up the progrtam

Comment: yeah i like to help my friends out. lol.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I've fixed it.

A better method would be to use py2exe. Download that from the source, then make a folder with your files. Create a setup.py file in that same folder and put

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['filename.py'])
```

shift+rightclick to run command prompt on the folder containing all this and then 
C:\Python34\Python setup.py install

then cut the stuff in the distribution folder out and paste it into the main folder with everything zip this up and its ready to go!